# how to format Time not Date on Android or Java?

Tags: android, time, format

I want to format the time like this: `2011-05-11 11:22:33`.

I had the following code:

```
Time time = new Time(MobiSageUtility.TIMEZONE_STRING);
time.setToNow();

String timeStr= time.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

However, that gives the date as: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` not `"2011-05-11 11:22:33"`.
After looking at the Android reference documents, I tried the following code:

```
 String timeStr = time.format2445();
```

But that gives a string like: `20110511T112233`.  Can somebody tell me how to format the time correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Date instead of Time and then use SimpleDateFormat.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String dateString = fmt.format(date);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: how to format Time not Date on Android or Java was what he asked.

Answer (score 22):

String timeStr= time.format("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S");

See man strftime as doc of method format explains:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: Thank you for answering the actual question rather than suggesting different usage.

Comment: Best answer that answers the actual question directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SimpleDateFormater](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String time = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat outFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
String dateString = outFmt.format(date);
```